# 2d convolution in tflearn CNN trashes learning for mnist and cifar-10 benchmarks

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow

I'm still learning how to implement tflearn networks, so bear with me. I tried the tflearn sample code from here: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_cifar10.py

Oddly though, the loss never dropped, and throughout training all I saw was a validation accuracy of 10% (equivalent to random with this dataset).

However, just commenting out the 2D convolution and max pooling operations, the validation accuracy jumps up to a validation accuracy of 0.47 in the first 10 epochs.

This is the modified code that seems to yeiled better results. The rest of the code is the same as in the above link

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3],
                     data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                     data_augmentation=img_aug)
#network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')
#network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
#network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
#network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')
#network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')
network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     learning_rate=0.001)
```

I was just somewhat concerned and confused that the example implementation given on tflearn's site was yielding random classifications when implementing a 2D convolution step. Has anyone else seen this before? Or can someone help me make intuitive sense why this might be happening? Or is this a symptom of a silent bug that crept into the conv_2d code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error in either the CUDA or CudNN libraries. The loss goes down and validation accuracy goes up right away if I turn off GPU computing before running the script.

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
python .....
```